# How to emit new structure that has no constructors

Tags: reflection, struct, reflection.emit

I trying to emit dynamic method that sets fields of class by some values and when type of regular field is struct I want to set field with new struct like this: `var myStruct = new SomeStruct( );`.

But I can't to find default constructor of that struct.

```
var type        = valueForField.GetType     ( );

if( type.IsValueType && !type.IsPrimitive && !type.IsEnum )
{
    emit
        .ldarg_0
        .newobj     ( type.GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes ) )
        .stfld      ( field );

    continue;
}
```

It fails at line `.newobj ( type.GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes ) )` because of passing null to **newobj** function

Can anybody tell me how to emit new structure creation through it default constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [initobj](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj.aspx)

```
.ldarg_0
.ldflda (field)
.initobj (type)
```

From msdn:

> Value types are not usually created using newobj. They are usually allocated either as arguments or local variables, using newarr (for zero-based, one-dimensional arrays), or as fields of objects. Once allocated, they are initialized using Initobj.

Answer (score 0):

`Struct`s can't have a real parameterless constructor. They have an implicit default constructor that's equivalent to `default(T)`.

It seems like the IL equivalent of `default(T)` is [`initobj`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj.aspx)

> Unlike Newobj, initobj does not call the constructor method. Initobj is intended for initializing value types, while newobj is used to allocate and initialize objects.

Comment: Just as a side note, while you can't create a parameterless constructor in C#, you can in .NET, so your first sentence is arguably inaccurate.  See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx.